# Matlab vs Excel differences in computations

Tags: matlab, excel, vba

I encountered some problem while using Matlab. I'm doing some computations concerning OTC instruments (pricing, constructing discount curve, etc.), firstly in Excel and after that in Matlab (for comparison). While I`m 100% sure that computations in Excel are good (comparing to market data), it seems that Matlab is producing some differences (i.e. -4,18-05E). Matlab algorithm looks fine. I was wondering - maybe it is because Matlab is rounding some computations - I heard a little bit about it. I'm trying to convert a double numbers to float by function **vpa()**, but it looks that it is not working with double numbers. Any other ideas?

Comment: I doubt Excel internally uses more precision than Matlab's `double`

Comment: Well, it looks like it is...

Comment: Anyway, it's hard to tell unless you post the code; preferably a small example that reproduces the precision problem

Comment: If you are comparing Matlab and Excel by copying the MATLAB output from the command line, then you should be aware that what `format` shows is not the "real" stored value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excel uses 64 bit double precision floating point numbers compliant with IEEE 754 floating point specification.

The way that Excel treats results like `=1/5` and *appears* to compute them exactly (despite this example not being a dyadic rational) is purely down to *formatting*. It handles `=1/3 + 1/3 + 1/3` similarly. It's quite smart really if you think about it: the implementers of Excel had no real choice given that the average Excel user is not *au fait* with the finer points of floating point arithmetic and would simply scorn a spreadsheet package that "couldn't even get `1/5` correct".

That all said, you're very unlucky if you get a difference of -4,18-05E between the two systems. That's because double floating point is accurate to around 15 significant figures. Your algorithms would be implemented very poorly indeed for the error terms to bubble up to that magnitude if you're consistently using double precision floating point types.

Most likely (and I too work in finance), the difference will be in the way you're interpolating your discount curve. That's where I would look first if I were you.

Answer (score 1):

Given the value of the error compared to the default `format` settings, this is almost certainly because of using the default `format short` and comparing the output on the command line to the real value.

```
x = 5.4444418
```

Output:

> x =
>
> ```
> 5.4444
> ```

Then:

```
x-5.4444
```

Output:

> ans =
>
> 4.1800e-05

The value stored in `x` remains at `5.4444418`, it is only the measure output to the command line that changes.